# Sending an email to a Facebook user, knowing only his id

Tags: facebook, email

If I send an email to `john.doe@facebook.com` then John will receive the message.

In my address book I have the Facebook ids of my friends.

Can I use those ids to send an email?
I just tried `12345@facebook.com` and I received "Recipient address does not exist" (I replaced 12345 with my own Facebook id).

How to send an email knowing only the id?

Comment: FYI: John Doe can receive an email at `john.doe@facebook.com` only if he enabled this feature.

Comment: @Alex: true at time of writing, but 8 months have passed and I believe the feature has been made opt-out now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send emails only to people who have usernames claimed. Facebook doesn't allow sending emails to IDs.

Below's my original (wrong) answer.

---

Yes, the email is `username@facebook.com`. Your friends should receive them as long as you send them from an email associated with your Facebook account because the default setting is to accept messages from at least friends.

You likely didn't receive your test message because your setting is currently something restrictive. Emails to `username@facebook.com` are controlled by the same setting as all messages sent on Facebook, which is "*Who can send you Facebook messages?*" under `How You Connect` in `Privacy Settings`.

Answer (score 2):

You can recover a user's facebook username through the Graph API. It is one of the few bits of data you can get on a user without them having authorized your application.

Visiting http://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_ID will return a JSON object containing the username, their name, and anything else they leave open to the public.

Answer (score 1):

Sending an email to a username is only effective if that particular name had the unlikely chance of being unique.  If there are several identical user names facebook assigns a number following the username.  To see the email address of a user, click on the ABOUT button on their home page.

Comment: I did not talk about usernames. I talked about ids. Every Facebook user has a unique id. It is a number like 10098419857324.